# Can't login: Can't get user info Bad Request in android studio

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I'm getting this issue while logging in on GitHub on Android Studio:

Can't login: Can't get user info  Bad Request

[image]

I have got my Git executed successfully Git version is 2.10.1.0
I have tried another account on my computer and it failed,too.I have use my account on another computer and it words. Plz help me to figure out this issue,thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try logging in with your Github username instead of your Github email address?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and could successfully login ticking the "no proxy" box in Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> HTTP Proxy.

[image]